# SQL Update only duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server

table_paysched

```
id |  ilno | acctno
1  |  1    | 001
2  |  1    | 001
3  |  2    | 001
4  |  1    | 002
5  |  1    | 002
6  |  0    | 003
7  |  1    | 003
```

I want to update the duplicate 1s ilno to 0. Thanks

Wanted Result

```
id |  ilno | acctno
1  |  0    | 001
2  |  1    | 001
3  |  2    | 001
4  |  0    | 002
5  |  1    | 002
6  |  0    | 003
7  |  1    | 003
```

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What is the desired output? Please edit your question and post that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTE` with window function `row_number` to do the update:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by acctno order by id desc) rn
    from t
    where ilno = 1
)
update cte
set ilno = 0
where rn <> 1;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/LYZFYT60823)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
with temp as (
    select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by acctno order by id desc) row_num,
    count() over (partition by acctno ) cnt_num
    from myTable
)

update myTable m
set m.ilno = 0
where exists (select 1 from temp t where m.id = t.id and t.row_num = 1 and cnt_num > 1)
```